# Hadoop: Getting error when i load file from source (i.e my PC) to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Im trying to copy a file from source to hdfs

Query: **Hadoop fs -copyFromLocal (Local path) (source path)**

e.g **Hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\users\Desktop  (source path)**

as well e.g **Hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\users\Desktop  URI**

but geting error

**-copyFromLocal: Can not create a Path from a null string
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] (localsrc) ... (dst)**

Answer (score 0):

try `hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal file_to_be_copied hdfs://namenode:/path_to_location`

fs command is being depreciated.

Note: you do not have to mention the actual HDFS path. You could also do something like

`hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal file_to_be_copied /path_to_location_within_hdfs`

Comment: can you plz tell how to find my hdfs path.. I have  given it correctly eventhough want to clarify..

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not specifying the path of file.
2. Make sure hdfs path that you specified exists.
3. Finally try escaping the forward slash like:

   ```
   Hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\\users\\Desktop\myfile.txt URI
   ```

Or use

```
    Hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:/users/Desktop/myfile.txt URI
```

Comment: Ya .. i have did the same earlier..  as well checked the path using pwd and given the hdfs path correctly...

Comment: Can u plz give a simple eg or a screenshot would be better.. As well can u plz tell me how to take a file and copy it into grunt...  ( I meant load a file from desktop to grunt)...

Comment: I have the example above. atm I don't have hadoop running or else i wouldh ave certainly shared screen shot. For the other request, please raise a new request as that's the follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am unable to comment below your reply.
The easiest way to to get the path is to go under the UI and click on "Browse the filesystem". Another option would be to `hdfs dfs -ls /`  or `hdfs dfs -lsr /`

`ls` will list the dir/files in your root dir.
`lsr` will recursively read through all the sub directories in your root dir.

Comment: HI ,I did  it.. Still unable to copy the file to hdfs...From desktop to hdfs cant able to do..

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is just like other file systems. The path begins with / as root. The period (.) denotes current directory. I am on Linux platform. Hope the examples below would help.

```
name@host: ~/oracle/sql$ hdfs dfs -ls /
Found 5 items
drwxr-xr-x   - myname supergroup          0 2014-09-05 03:06 /directory
drwxr-xr-x   - myname supergroup          0 2014-05-10 03:34 /in
drwxr-xr-x   - myname supergroup          0 2014-10-16 22:50 /system
drwxrwx---   - myname supergroup          0 2014-08-18 08:44 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - myname supergroup          0 2014-08-18 08:41 /user
name@host: ~/oracle/sql$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal foo.sql /
name@host: ~/oracle/sql$ hdfs dfs -ls /
Found 6 items
drwxr-xr-x   - myname supergroup          0 2014-09-05 03:06 /directory
-rw-r--r--   3 myname supergroup         90 2015-03-24 05:33 /foo.sql
drwxr-xr-x   - myname supergroup          0 2014-05-10 03:34 /in
drwxr-xr-x   - myname supergroup          0 2014-10-16 22:50 /system
drwxrwx---   - myname supergroup          0 2014-08-18 08:44 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - myname supergroup          0 2014-08-18 08:41 /user

name@name: ~/oracle/sql$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal foo.sql /user/myname/
name@name: ~/oracle/sql$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/myname/foo.sql
-rw-r--r--   3 myname supergroup         90 2015-03-24 05:41       /user/myname/foo.sql
name@host: ~/oracle/sql$
```